# generating a query to join distinct records

Tags: mysql, hive

A newbie in sql/ hive...

```
 SELECT id,seed, day FROM  table_1 WHERE  day = to_date('2016-06-09') limit 5;
302766500   R388899 2016-06-09
692010468   R61140  2016-06-09
662084962   R165803 2016-06-09
1818260515  R411276 2016-06-09
646246322   R426737 2016-06-09


SELECT id, exp, day FROM table_2 WHERE day = to_date('2016-06-09')  limit 5;
OK
2595    e137_1  2016-06-09
2595    e137_2  2016-06-09
4372    e137_1  2016-06-09
7256    e137_1  2016-06-09
18674   e137_1  2016-06-09
Time taken: 1.475 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

As you can see in table 2.. listener id is repeated (2595)..

So, from table 2, I want to find out the distinct ids between two day ranges

and then find the seed of those ids from table 1 between a given date range..

```
SELECT id, seed FROM table_1 WHERE day = to_date('some date')
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_2 WHERE day = to_date('some_date')
) l
ON l.id = id;
```

But i get this error:

```
ParseException line 3:0 missing EOF at 'JOIN' near ')'
```

Comment: are you sure that tag `mysql` is relevant with your question?

Comment: maybe not.. I am new in hive.. but everyone has been saying to me, that is sql..

Comment: I suppose, it's Oracle function(`to_date`)

Comment: If you're new in SQL, the first thing you should do is study a tutorial on basic syntax. It's fine to come here for help with logic, but you really should be able to get the order of clauses correct from educational material.

Comment: @Barmar: yeah.. thats a good suggestion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems the where is in wrong position

```
SELECT table_1.id, table_1.seed FROM table_1 
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_2 WHERE day = to_date('some_date')
) l
ON l.id = table_1.id
WHERE table_1.day = to_date('some date')

;
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10008]: Line 6:19 Ambiguous table alias 'id' 
On the join condition line (l.id = id)
also, this is hive.. if that helps .

Answer (score 1):

Join always in the from section:

```
SELECT id, seed FROM table_1 JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_2 WHERE day = to_date('some_date')
) l
ON l.id = table_1.id
WHERE day = to_date('some date')
```

Comment: I am getting this error FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10008]: Line 6:19 Ambiguous table alias 'id' On the join condition line (l.id = id) also, this is hive.. if that helps

Comment: You need to use the table name `table_1.id` instead of just `id`

Comment: yes like he said   this erreur appears when you have two table having the same field name like here    we have  table generated by statement we give it alias L  and we have the table_1   both have the same field id so you need to undicate wich table the "id" belong to  sorry for my poor english